# What are the best Together mode weapon sets?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Everybody is extremely over-powered in Kid Icarus: Uprising. Therefore, I need some ideas on how to be on the same level of strength as them. Can anyone give me ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to have weapons that specialize in melee attacks and weapons that specialize in ranged attacks. For both types of weapons, you'll want as high of a rating for its given damage type as possible (6 stars if possible); don't worry about the other damage type. overall defense and health modifiers are always very helpful too. Remember that higher value weapons are not always more useful, and enemies will get more points for killing you when you have a higher value weapon, so you want to balance power and value.

For **ranged** weapons, most players prefer staffs. Staffs and clubs are good choices for sniping, while palms, orbitars, and bows are good choices if you want high homing ability.

Charged shot and continuous fire modifiers are great for ranged weapons. Full-health boosts can be good if you plan to shoot from afar. Shot homing and shot cancellation are extremely helpful, but remember that shot homing modifiers won't help weapons that have no inherent homing ability.

For **melee** weapons, most players choose claws. Claws are great for melee because they hit faster than any other weapon type, and also give you a speed boost. Arms and clubs can be good for dealing a lot of damage in a short time, but won't give you the speed boost and constant hits that claws will.

Obviously, you'll want melee combo +4 and melee dash attack +4 modifiers. Other especially useful modifiers include freezing, petrification, stamina, and speed bonuses.

See [Icarus Wiki's weapons pages](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Weapon) for individual weapons. There's a lot of useful information there for deciding which weapon you want to use, but it's not complete.

---

As for [powers](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Power), you'll want to pick ones that work well with your weapon, but also ones that you like playing. I personally love destructive powers such as Mega Laser or Explosive Flame.

For ranged weapons, Homing Boost, Quick Charge, and Slip Shot are very useful. If you're using a club for ranged attacks you should try Invisible Shots too, so your enemies don't see your shots coming.

For melee weapons, Black Hole is great for holding your enemies in place while you wail on them, as are Paralyze Attack and Petrify Attack. Interference, Darkness, and Transparency can help you sneak up on them without being seen. Tirelessness is invaluable when it comes to engaging and disengaging combat. Playing Dead is especially fun to use when fighting another melee player.

Comment: What if I had a club with Trade-Off and Energy Charge? Is that strong?

Comment: @IcarusNerd Both are powerful abilities and have similar weaknesses. Both take up a fairly large piece of the power grid. Also both are powers that you only want to use if you don't think you'll be hit soon afterward, since Energy Charge ends when you're hit, and Trade-Off leaves you very vulnerable. You could combine them with Transparency to help combat that. To get a similar effect in a more flexible way, try getting a high ranged damage club with full-health boost and forward-dash ch. shot modifiers, and bring health recovery to get back to full health after being hit.

Comment: Or just use Spite in an area with a bunch of people?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest trying to make a suicide bomber build for together mode. If you're looking for AoE attacks, a cannon and the Explosive Flame work well. Note that AoE isn't particularly useful in Light vs Dark because there are only 3 enemies on the entire map.

Comment: What cannon exactly? Would Doom Cannon work for that? And what does AoE mean?

Comment: @IcarusNerd AoE means "area of effect", which is simply damage (or other effects) that hit an area rather than a single target. The Doom Cannon does have good AoE damage, but keep in mind that it has a long charge time and its shots travel slowly. Any cannon should be good for hitting an area aside from the Ball Cannon and Cragalanche Cannon. It's good to try them all out and see which suits you best, since they all have different effects. See http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Cannon for some basic info.

Comment: Does Doom Cannon have the biggest AoE? Is the Lancer Staff a balanced weapon? I'm looking mostly for sets that are the most powerful, but don't leave you open. So I'm looking for shot cancellation, & power.

Comment: I don't know which cannon has the biggest blast radius, although the Dynamo Cannon is coming to mind for having a large blast (but less damage than most cannons). The Lancer Staff is fairly well balanced since it has strong ranged attacks and also strong melee for a staff. I often use a Lancer Staff in solo mode. It has fast moving charged shots but little (if any) homing ability. Cannons, clubs, and arms generally have good shot cancellation and high power.

Comment: I meant its Together performance. And what cannons have cancellation? What sets would be very sneaky?

Comment: All weapons have a certain cancellation value. I think the Ball Cannon has the highest cancellation value, but its shots don't explode like other cannons. If you're trying to make a sneaky set, I recommend the Transparency and Invisible Shots, but Slip Shot, Darkness, Interference, Tirelessness, Playing Dead, and Spin Attack would work well too. Claws are good for short range sneaky sets, while staffs are good for long range. Either way, you should use a weapon with a speed modifier to help you sneak around faster.

Comment: What's the second highest?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might want to try out the Rail, Doom, Cragalanche, and Leo Cannons. Those are the ones that I have a feeling also have high cancellation, but that's just a hunch. If you have a friend that you can play against in local together mode, you can test it out by shooting charged shots at each other at the same time with different cannons and seeing which shot powers through.

Comment: Ok thanks but what overall weapon has highest cancellation? (other than Guardian Orbitars)

Comment: I'm not sure which is the highest, but other ones with high cancellation are the Black Club, Aurum Club, Hawkeye Bow, Divine Bow, Centurion Orbitars, Palutena Blade, Burst Blade, Crusader Blade, and Midnight Palm.

Comment: And how do you unlock Centurion Orbitars and Aurum Club?

Comment: Centurion Orbitars are unlocked by defeating the Chariot Master while in Crisis Mode, and the Aurum Club is unlocked by completing chapter 15 in less than 17 minutes. By the way, I noticed that you haven't accepted answers to any of your questions yet. If you want to accept an answer to one of your questions, you can click on the check mark to the left of it. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for details.

Comment: What about powers to counter other powers and items?

Comment: If you name the powers or items that you're looking to counter, I can advise you on what I think would work best against them. If it's going to be extensive, you should probably make it a new question though.

Comment: Just O.P. powers and items I want to counter.

Comment: Having a Status Resistance modifier on your weapon or the Effect Recovery power can be very helpful for countering many items and powers, particularly ones that petrify or freeze you. With some practice, Reflect Barrier can be effective against thrown items or projectiles. Using a weapon with Speed or Running Speed boosts is helpful for picking up items before your opponents, especially if you're trying to prevent them from completing Daybreak. If all else fails, the Brief Invincibility power can be used as a "panic button" in case you get into a particularly bad situation.

Comment: What about Cyclone item & Blsck Hole power?

Comment: There isn't much you can do once you're sucked into one of those, but Brief Invincibility can be used to negate whatever damage they were planning to hit you with while you were stuck or Warp can be used to escape. Also, weapons with higher speed can help you run out of the pull so you don't get caught in the first place.

Comment: What do I do when fighting Japanese players? They're number one when it comes to overpoweredness.

Comment: Practice? Play when they're asleep? Don't know what to tell you there.

Comment: Whenever I fight Japanese players they kill me in EXACTLY one hit.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting sniped. Try bringing weapons with Health, Defense, or Shot Defense modifiers. If they're sniping you with staffs, find their favorite sniping spots and keep an eye on them. Forcing them into melee combat should give you an advantage against any sniping build, even if you aren't running a melee focused build. And if it's someone named Brian killing you in one hit with an Ore Club and Invisible Shots, you should definitely not attack him in melee. ;)

Comment: Well you see, people also use Brawler Claws and I think they're hacking because they can basically move as fast as the power Warp, and can practically fly, and my attacks NEVER land.

Comment: Those players are probably using the Brawler Claws that you get from Treasure Hunt with +8 Defense, +4 Speed, and +1 Stamina. They might have also added powers to help them run faster just for fun. The catch is that they have 0 stars of damage, so they should be mostly harmless.

Comment: Well what I meant by fly is sometimes they go super high on the map Lava Basin

Comment: There are jump pads in Lava Basin, but if they're staying in the air, they're probably using the Jump Glide power. That shouldn't be much of a problem for any weapon with decent homing ability.

Comment: But they go like, 150 ft into the air. Also, in the cave arena, they somehow walljump off the pillars

Comment: There definitely isn't wall-jumping in KIU. The only legitimate ways to "fly" are via powers, jump pads or cyclones, but I can't say for certain that there isn't some sort of flight hack.

Comment: Once in the Solo mode, Palutena said you can reflect shots with clubs. Is this true in Together? If so, how?

Comment: Clubs' continuous fire doesn't actually shoot anything, but instead can be used to bat back incoming projectiles. It's a lot more useful/reliable in Air Battles than on land.

Comment: But does it work against PvP shots is what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes. Wow, it was more than a year since my previous comment.

Comment: Ok cool. What's the best way to do it? Do you use a dash?

Comment: No, just hold down the button to shoot while standing or walking. Bigger and slower shots are easier to reflect, and not all projectiles can be reflected (the Flintlock Staff comes to mind). Shots from orbitars, cannons, and arms are probably the easiest to reflect.